# PHP Mysqli Query Fails

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert

I have the following code, but the Problem is, the Query fails, nothing gets insertet. EVEN when `$has_serial` is false, nothing gets insertet.

If i remove the `if ($has  Serial`... the Query in the ELSE works fine.

Why is that?

```
       $data6=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM basket WHERE user='$user'");
          while($info6=mysqli_fetch_array($data6)){


    $article=$info6['article'];
    $amount=$info6['amount'];
    $amount= -$amount;

    $data7=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM article WHERE articlenr ='$article'");
    while($info7 =mysqli_fetch_array($data7)){
        $art_name=$info7['articletext'];
        $has_serial=$info7['has_serial'];
    }

    if ($has_serial = true){
        $i = 1;
        while ($i <= $amount){
            mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO bookings (amount,article, articlename,BI_ID,user) VALUES ('$amount','$article','$art_name','$BI_ID','$user')");
            $i++;
            }

    }
    else
    {

        mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO bookings (amount,article, articlename,BI_ID,user) VALUES ('$amount','$article','$art_name','$BI_ID','$user')");
    }



}
```

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will probably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your if statement is written wrong. `$has_serial = true` is always true, so it always fall in this case, because `$has_serial` first become equal to true then it is evaluated.

```
if ($has_serial = true){
```

Should be:

```
if ($has_serial == true){
```

I adopted a good convention from WordPress codex which is adopted from other conversions back to C/C++ development. First write the const expression then the variable one like:

```
if(true == $has_serial)
```

This way if you make a mistake the interpreter will throw an error, instead of unexpected behavior, which may take a lot of time to locate its source. I have wasted hours for errors like this, when I was young programmer, even these days it may take my head off for few minutes, which is a waste for me.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the Problem in case `$has_Serial` is false. But the Query dont work when ist true!

Comment: @HKK I would guess `$amount` is negative, so your `while` loop will never run.

Comment: Check your input in the query to verify its consistence. also check the while loop as @jeroen says. Debug its value with `echo` or `print`.

Comment: @HKK it has to be negative, for calculating purposes, if its not negative, the STOCK of a Product will be raised when you sell something, whats not correct,

Comment: @HKK And what do you think happens here after setting `$i` to 1: `$i <= $amount`

Comment: Then you probably want to change it to `while($i >= $amount)` and reduce `$i` with `$i--`. Otherwise, this will be endless loop. Depends on your business logic (what you want to achieve). Definitely, the logic seems messed up, to me, @HKK.

Comment: thank you :D i fixed it, i did an extra variable for the amount thing. :)

Comment: @NKK, see also what *tadman* have written in a comment under the question, about **SQL Injections**. It is very important topic, even if it is not related to the problem.

Comment: @Rolice i dont understand the point of tadman's post... what should be wrong by insert an "-1" into an integer database field...this works fine, since about 8 years in our company system

Comment: @HKK, an SQL Injection is method where a person as regular visior of the system may inject SQL of his own in your query. For example, `DELETE FROM users` and if you don't filter it he will delete anything he wants (and finds). See the following explanations and methods of protection:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection and https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/

Comment: @HKK, its not for the **-1** it may be anywhere else where such queries exists. If no one have exploited it yet does not mean it will not happen at all. Its a recommendation of his ;)